# How to add a 'global' component into a ListView qml?

Tags: qt, qml

Context: I'm trying to create the layout of your typical video editor. Right now, I'm using a ListView as a timeline for the user to edit their video clips.

The ListView is a list of rows.

What I want to achieve is: I want to click anywhere on the ListView, and have a cursor be placed on that position. As I scroll horizontally on the ListView, I want that cursor to stay put, until I click on the ListView again.

What I have tried:

```
  ListView {
    id: timeline
    width: main.contentWidth
      anchors.fill         : parent
      ScrollBar.vertical   : ScrollBar {}
      ScrollBar.horizontal : ScrollBar {}
      flickableDirection   : Flickable.HorizontalAndVerticalFlick
      boundsBehavior       : Flickable.StopAtBounds
      contentWidth         : main.contentWidth
      model                : VideoList{}
      delegate             : VideoLayer{}
}
```

```
VideoLayer {
    id : layer

    Rectangle {
        width           : 10000
        height          : 100
        color           : main.bgColor
        border.color    : "black"
        border.width    : 2

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill    : parent
            onPressed       :
              (mouse) =>{
                           cursor.x      = mouseX
                           console.log(mouse.x)
                       }
        }
        Rectangle{
          id     : cursor
          x      : 0
          height : parent.height
          width  : 10
          color  : "white"
        }
}
```

The problem with this is that, a cursor is defined for each video layer. Clicking on the ListView only updates the cursor position for that layer. I want the cursor to be 'global' in a sense, where the cursor should be synchronised over each layer.

Comment: Your cursor should be a child of the **ListView** itself. Then, try to bind its `x` to `contentX` of the ListView, like this: `x: pinnedX - timeline.contentX`. Now, the cursor moves by scrolling the **ListView**'s content.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

- define an outer Flickable and house all your timelines within
- declare a global property for the position of interest

```
Page {
    property int pos: 50
    Flicklable {
        id: flickable
        contentWidth: columnLayout.width
        contentHeight: columnLayout.height
        ColumnLayout {
            id: columnLayout
            ListView { id: timeline1 }
            ListView { id: timeline2 }
            ListView { id: timeline3 }
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        x: pos - flickable.contentX
        y: 0
        width: 1
        height: flickable.height
    }
}
```

As to updating the position, each ListView can override the default TapHandler, as follows:

```
ListView {
    TapHandler {
        onTapped: pos = eventPoint.position.x
    }
}
```

Here's a mock example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    title: "Video Timelines"
    property int pos: 50
    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        width: parent.width
        height: columnLayout.height
        contentWidth: columnLayout.width
        contentHeight: columnLayout.height
        ColumnLayout {
            id: columnLayout
            width: 2000
            ListView {
                id: timeline1
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 150
                orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                model: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
                delegate: TimelineDelegate { }
                TapHandler {
                    onTapped: pos = eventPoint.position.x
                }
            }
            ListView {
                id: timeline2
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 150
                orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                model: [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
                delegate: TimelineDelegate { }
                TapHandler {
                    onTapped: pos = eventPoint.position.x
                }
            }
            ListView {
                id: timeline3
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 150
                orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                model: [0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
                delegate: TimelineDelegate { }
                TapHandler {
                    onTapped: pos = eventPoint.position.x
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        x: pos - flickable.contentX
        y: 0
        width: 3
        height: 500
        color: "red"
        border.color: "yellow"
    }
}

// TimelineDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 150
    border.color: "black"
    color: "gray"
    Rectangle {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width: parent.width - 2
        height: parent.height * modelData / 10
        x: 1
        y: parent.height - height - 1
        color: "green"
        border.color: "yellow"
        
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)